# Jekyll:Use front matter in permalinks

Tags: jekyll

According to [Jekyll Docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/), you can add categories to the permalink like so: `/:categories`, but what if I want to use front matter that isn't categories? For example, I have a front matter named `state`. I tried  adding `/:state` to no avail.

For example: `state/:state` is my permalink. In my front matter I have the following:

```
---
state: tx
---
```

So then my url will be `state/tx`.

I realize that I can create a custom permalink in the front matter of each page, but I am looking for something automatic as I am having less savvy users update the site. Also, `categories` isn't an obvious indicator that a state abbreviation should go there for my content managers.

Answer (score 3):

as you may have already noticed. using a [default front matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#front-matter-defaults) for states' page can achieve that. can achieve the automatic permalink generation.

by adding the following to `_config.yml`:

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: "_states"                       # states' page location
    values:
      permalink: /state/:categories/:slug/
```

and in each page, using a yaml front matter like:

```
---
category: tx
---
```

**But** if you want to get ride of the "category" here, and you can use local plaguing with your website (for example github page doesn't support them by default) then add a [generator](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#generators) that run before the site is generated, looks for the `state` value from the yaml front mater of each page, and put it in the appropriate folder.

Comment: Yeah, Default Front Matter is a dope feature, but Jekyll Admin doesn't allow for it. I might have to do that generator option, which looks promising.

Comment: then, check the 2nd code sample in [jekyll doc generator](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#generators), and use [#read_yaml](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mojombo/jekyll/Jekyll%2FConvertible%3Aread_yaml) to get the yaml values before processing

Comment: Thanks bud, I understand it will be some trickery but I've been figuring out jekyll alright so far.

Comment: yep, an other option, if you like playing with ruby code is to get [parse the yaml](http://yaml4r.sourceforge.net/doc/) directly, looks for the `"state: state-value"`, and add `category: state-value`. it's less jekyll-ish. and a bit hacky .. but it's another option :)

Comment: important note: this only works with _post content type. This will not work on collections https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/#collections

Answer (score 0):

That "act as a placeholder", you won't see /:categories in your URLs, it says that if a post you made belonging to a category, the name of the post category will go there.

For example: having a post with the following front matter :

```
---
categories: mycat
---
```

Then that post URL will start with **/mycat/...**.

If you want custom variables included in the front matter to be replaced in perm a links, that can't be done. You can just add custom strings to the permalinks but not variables.

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware that I can add `:categories` in my permalink, but what about custom front matter like ':state'. For example:
`
---
state: tx
---
`
Then the URL for `/:state/` would show as `/tx/`

Comment: argh, well hopefully it will be possible in the future.